# how to get values of textbox, calendar, and ddl on main page through web user control used on web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

"i'm new in asp.net, and i cant get values from user control to main page. please help me by giving me sol.
i create a web user control on web form and use textbox, calendar, and ddl in user control, now i want to get values of textbox, calendar, and ddl on main page. following is code of ascx page

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:Label>
<br />
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="Beige" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlthings" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlthings_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem> Apple</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Banana</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Mango</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Grapes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="lblthings" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<script runat="server">
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //display the text in textbox
        lblData.Text = txtData.Text;
    }
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //display the selected date of calender
        Label1.Text = "Your selected Date is: " +
            Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
    protected void ddlthings_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //display the selected thing of dropdownlist
        lblthings.Text = "Your selected Thing is: " + ddlthings.SelectedValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you just need to register the control in your aspx page.

Comment: i've already registr

Comment: what error are u getting then ?

Comment: out put is showing on the Default.aspx page where i'm using the control but i want that the item i choose should be show on outside the control(main page).

Answer (score 0):

somthing like that:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //display the text in textbox
    lblData.Text = txtData.Text;
    // retrive data from controls
    var text = ((TextBox)txtData).Text;
    var calendarValue = ((Calendar)Calendar1).SelectedDate;
    var ddlValue = ((DropDownList)ddlthings).SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: the aspx page is lik this
<%@ Register src="CalendarUserControl.ascx" tagname="CalendarUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<script runat="server">     
</script>  
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
    <title></title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>    
        <uc1:CalendarUserControl ID="CalendarUserControl1" runat="server" />
             </div>
    </form>  
</body>
    </html>